# Plone: remove Home tab in front page for anonymous users

Tags: plone

I don't know how hide the Home tab in front page for Anonymous users, Plone version is 4.3.7.
Better should be hide the navigation bar, and I've found to do this through ZMI portal_actions/portal_tabs/index_html  and uncheck visible. But after, also the user logged in doesn't view the bar.
Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `python: member is not None` to the condition of index_html action.

[image]